# Discord bot Embed not returning text as I wanted

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

Making a discord bot and this one of the commands, it should return a embed but ` ruin the text:

```
module.exports = {
        name: 'pain',
        description: 'Pain',
        execute(message, args) {
             const Discord = require('discord.js');
             const PainEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Tears')
            .setAuthor('A fork')
            .setDescription(`
                If I showed you my teardrops,
                Would you collect them like rain,
                Store them in jars,
                That are labelled with "pain"
                Would you follow their tracks,
                From my eyes down my cheeks,
                As they write all the stories,
                I\`m too scared to speak,
                Would you stop them with kisses,
                Bring their flow to a halt,
                as you teach me that pain,
                Isen\`t always my fault,
                Would you hold my face gently,
                As you dry both my eyes,
                And whisper the words, 
                "You\`re too precious to cry",
                If I showed you my teardrops,
                Would you show me your own,
                And learn though we\`re lonely,
                We\`re never alone. `)
            .setFooter('Poem made by: ~e.h');
            message.channel.send(PainEmbed);
        },
    };
```

this is what the code returns:

[image]

I think it returns a promise,and I have to resolve the promise but I dont know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple because you're using Discord's code block feature.
Not really sure why you're using ` instead of ' because honestly, it looks better and is correct English-wise.

```
Simply change it from ` to ' in the cases where you want an apostrophe.
```

In that case you won't even need to use \ before ' either.